# Is there a Sketch search/replace function for primary hexadecimal colors?

Tags: color, sketch-app, interface-design

I created 20 website templates with multiple layers and assets.

I use a primary pallet of five colors.

These colors need to be changed and I would like to use the DRY concept. If this was a prototype in HTML/SASS - I would just change the primary set colors across the whole site.

Is there a native function that can search for a particular hexadecimal color and replace it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Sketch has native color find & replace:
[image]

There are also [plugins](https://github.com/lewishowles/sketch-replace-colour) with similar functionalities.

And, last but not least, you can make use of [nested symbols and overrides](https://medium.com/design-prototype/sketch-tint-icons-using-nested-symbols-2d52867e0d29), creating symbols with your usual fill colors that you then can update once and have it propagate across your documents, and [layer styles](https://medium.com/sketch-app-sources/using-shared-styles-and-symbols-in-sketch-8cab4650dc55) that will also require you to update in one place only.